# wrong modal popup on click (html, css, js)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i'm having trouble figuring out how to have each example have a modal with it's own content. currently, if i click EXAMPLE2, the content from EXAMPLE1 still pops up. i also am not sure why the icons or the modals don't work on here, but i'm hoping someone can at least give pointers based on the code here. i tried changing the IDs to be unique, but i don't think i'm doing it correctly? thank you in advance

```js
function togglePopup(){
  document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
}
function togglePopup(){
  document.getElementById("popup-2").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.icon-inner {
  width: 120px;
  /*height: 40vh;*/
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  /*position: relative;*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/*.icon-inner span {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}*/

.icon-inner span:before {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.icon-inner span:hover {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #4FC1E9;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.icon-inner-info span:before {
  height: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  /*float: flex;*/
  position: relative;
}

.icon-inner-info span:hover {
  margin-left: 0;
  cursor: help;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.icon-inner-info .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  left: 110%;
}

.icon-inner-info .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}

.icon-inner-info:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}


.popup .overlay {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index:1;
  display:none;
}

.popup .content-pop {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
  background:#fff;
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
  z-index:2;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family:"Open Sans",sans-serif;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  cursor:pointer;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:20px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:#222;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:600;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.popup.active .overlay {
  display:block;
}

.popup.active .content-pop {
  transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform:translate(50%,-50%) scale(1);
}

@media(max-width: 750px) {
  .popup.active .content-pop { 
    transform:translate(-10%,-50%) scale(1);
  } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initialpscale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!-- link for back to top button -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous"> --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font/flaticon.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--  -->


  </head>
<body>
  <div class="icon-inner">
                  <span class="flaticon-statistics" onclick="togglePopup()"></span>
                  <p>TITLE1</p>
                    <!-- <p class="tooltiptext">Interviewing, notetaking, storytelling</p> -->
                  <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <div class="content-pop">
                      <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
                      <h1>Title1</h1>
                      <p>example1</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
  <div class="icon-inner">
                  <span class="flaticon-statistics" onclick="togglePopup()"></span>
                  <p>TITLE2</p>
                    <!-- <p class="tooltiptext">Interviewing, notetaking, storytelling</p> -->
                  <div class="popup" id="popup-2">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <div class="content-pop">
                      <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
                      <h1>Title2</h1>
                      <p>example2</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: you can't have 2 elements with the same id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially your problem was duplicate IDs. However, after changing them the problem became having the same name for two different functions.

The simplest solution is to pass to the function the ID that you want to open:

For testing purposes, I removed all of your CSS because the popup wasn't aligning correctly.

The word OPEN in my example is your open icon. It works the same, just doesn't have the icon.

```js
function togglePopup(id){
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.popup{display:none;}
.active{display:block;}
```

```html
  <div class="icon-inner">
                  <span class="flaticon-statistics" onclick="togglePopup('popup-1')">OPEN</span>
                  <p>TITLE1</p>
                    <!-- <p class="tooltiptext">Interviewing, notetaking, storytelling</p> -->
                  <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <div class="content-pop">
                      <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup('popup-1')">&times;</div>
                      <h1>Title1</h1>
                      <p>example1</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
  <div class="icon-inner">
                  <span class="flaticon-statistics" onclick="togglePopup('popup-2')">OPEN</span>
                  <p>TITLE2</p>
                    <!-- <p class="tooltiptext">Interviewing, notetaking, storytelling</p> -->
                  <div class="popup" id="popup-2">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <div class="content-pop">
                      <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup('popup-2')">&times;</div>
                      <h1>Title2</h1>
                      <p>example2</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: should i be using 'popup-1' and 'popup-2' in the span and close-btn div? it didn't work for me. feel free to edit the code above

Comment: @J.Doe I updated my answer with a working example that stripped out some of your HTML/CSS to simplify my answer. But it is working adding that to ALL calls to `togglePopup`.

Comment: amazing. i didn't realize you meant literally using 'id' in js. i was using 'popup-1' and 'popup-2'. i'm pretty new to this so appreciate your help! thank you again